# Use google cloud storage to hosting maven repository

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, bitbucket, google-cloud-storage

I use Gradle on  Android Studio 1.1, I can use the "maven-publish" Plugin. With this one, I can publish to repositories.

Can I use the google cloud storage to host a maven repository?

Or I have to create a Bitbucket/Github to make this?

Thanks

Comment: What about https://bintray.com/?

Comment: It's a private project, bintray is too expensive for us. @PaoloFulgoni

Comment: Have you also considered a private [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) server?

Comment: It's very expensive too.. [price](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/buy-now/) @PaoloFulgoni

Comment: We use the open source edition on an Windows server. You could even run it on a Linux VM.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean? @PaoloFulgoni

Comment: I mean that my company has an Artifactory instance, open source edition, on an internal server and we publish to that server. It's free and works great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74411/discussion-between-paolo-fulgoni-and-david-cesar-santos).

Answer (score 9):

You can have a Google Cloud Storage Bucket act as a remote maven repository to host your artifacts and dependencies only if you do not require the need to have those artifacts and dependencies updated more than once per second.  While there is no limit on the number of objects that you can create in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and there is no limit to writes across multiple objects, there is an Update limit on each object of once per second; so rapid writes to a single object won’t scale.

That being said, you can [configure a Google Cloud Storage Bucket as a Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration#tip-dynamic) and use it as your remote repository.

By default, Maven will download from the central repository. To override this, you need to specify your GCS Bucket in your pom.xml as shown in [Using Mirrors for Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).

To upload your artifacts to your bucket you must authenticate with a username and password in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file. The username and password need to be retrieved from the [Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com):
In the menu on the left select Storage → Settings > > Interoperability.
If no keys are listed under **Interoperable storage access keys**, select "Create a new key".
Use the Access Key as username, and Secret as the password

Comment: tried to configure this, but always getting Forbidden. Is there more configuration required? Will be glad if you ca shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a private Maven repository using https://github.com/renaudcerrato/appengine-maven-repository.

Make a separate App Engine project yourcompanyname-maven.appspot.com.

Setup the username / password configuration and you're all set.