# Google cloud storage Authentication for private maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-3, google-cloud-storage

I tried to setup a maven repository on a google storage bucket. I followed the answer in this post: 
[Use google cloud storage to hosting maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408256/use-google-cloud-storage-to-hosting-maven-repository)

So i added the maven plugin in my build.gradle and created this task:

```
dependencies {
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
}
.....
apply plugin: 'maven'
.....
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        configuration = configurations.deployerJars
        pom.version = '1.0.0'
        pom.groupId = 'org.example'
        pom.artifactId = 'example-lib'
        repository(url: "http://maven.example.org/maven3") {
            authentication(userName: "KeyID", password: "Secret")
        }
    }
}
```

"maven.exmaple.org" has a CNAME entry to point to "c.storage.googleapis.com.".

As suggested in the link above i activated the interoperability and created a new key. (KeyID and the secret)
I added them in the gradle script as authentication bean.

When i call

> ./gradlew uploadArchives

I always get "Access denied" from google.

What I'm doing wrong here?
Any suggestions?

Thank you